# Google Sheets need to return different values in a column based on multiple criteria in another

Tags: google-sheets

I am working in Google Sheets and I am drawing a blank. Column A are a list of criteria which may repeat any number of times. Column B are Yes/No responses to those criteria. Column C needs to return "Fully Implemented" if all answers are Yes, "Not Implemented" if all answers are "No" and "Partially Implemented" if there are a combination of yes and no responses on each instance of the question. I have attached an image that may assist. I appreciate any help.

[image: SAMPLE DATA]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, thank you for your help.

=@IFS(COUNTIFS(A:A,@A:A,O:O,"yes")/COUNTIF(A:A,@A:A)=1,"Fully Implemented",COUNTIFS(A:A,@A:A,O:O,"yes")/COUNTIF(A:A,@A:A)=0,"Not Implemented",AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,@A:A,O:O,"yes")/COUNTIF(A:A,@A:A)<1,COUNTIFS(A:A,@A:A,O:O,"yes")/COUNTIF(A:A,@A:A)>0),"Partially Implemented")

Answer (score 1):

Try `LOOKUP` + `COUNTIF/-S`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A:A),LOOKUP((COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,"Yes"))+(COUNTIF(A:A,A:A)=COUNTIFS(A:A,A:A,B:B,"No"))*2,{0,1,2},{"Partially implemented","Fully implemented","Not implemented"}),))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does not appear to work when I change a response. For instance, If I change the response in C7 to "No", C6, C7, and C8 should all change to "not implemented." Even if I delete and repaste the formula, they do not change.  Thoughts?

Comment: @user17074375 I checked - the formula works. Here is the link to the file [lookup_countif](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W0JoZaVNhFPsxMTR-sFVAoOoHIUfoLpzsOis8BdRhm0/edit?usp=sharing)